# Bootstrap Panel with horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Been going round & round in circles. I've got a Bootstrap 3 panel and within the panel-body I'm adding divs dynamically (MVC razor) which are stacked:

```
.test-result {
  float: right;
  width: 150px !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  border: solid 1px;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  background-color: lightgray;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Once these exceed the width of the panel-body they obviously start stacking etc.

I want the panel-body content to stay side by side and to have a horizontal scrollbar. I've added overflow-x: scroll etc and nowrap but had no joy. Please help :)

Comment: Add an outer container to the list containing `'div` elements. Give a specific width to this container and an overflow-x auto.

Comment: Can you add a plunkr ?

Comment: yep... that might help :)

https://embed.plnkr.co/gAOEojiBCNkU0E7FCiox/

so i dont want the divs inside the panel to stack. i want a scrollbar across the bottom so I could have 100 divs etc...

Comment: Check my answer below. Hope that is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update your CSS like below**

You can define the with of `resultContainer` based on the number of child containers you want to scroll through. So if each `test-result` is `150px` in width and you want to accommodate `100` such containers then make the width of `resultContainer` to be 150 x 100 i.e 15000px.

```
<style>
    .tab-pane{
        width:100%;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      .resultContainer{
          width:600px;    //4 containers x 150px
      }
      .test-result {
          float: left;
          width: 150px !important;
          height: 100% !important;
          border: solid 1px;
          min-height: 100% !important;
          background-color: lightgray;
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto;
          padding-left: 15px;
          padding-right: 15px;
          display: inline-block;
          white-space: normal;
    }
    .new-test-group {
        float: left;
        width: 150px !important;
        height: 100% !important;
        border: solid 1px;
        min-height: 100% !important;
        background-color: lightgreen;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        display: inline-block;
        white-space: normal;    
    }
    .eachNewTest {
        border: solid 1px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
```

> **UPDATE** - Adding with width of .resultContainer dynamically

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        let resultContainerWidth = 150;
        let resultContainerCount = $('.test-result').length;
        $('.resultContainer').width(resultContainerWidth * resultContainerCount);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: This is super close and works but I'm having to hardcode the .resultContainer width. if thats set as say 1000px then as soon as theres 8 divs within it, they start stacking again. 

I could obviously make this a large number/size but then I've got a huge white space thats scrollable. 

Hope that makes sense???

Comment: unless this can be a dynamic width... I'll just set it v.large and put up with the white space. Many Thanks

Comment: You need to use JavaScript my friend. @daFunk
There is no other way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a div like this:

```
<div class="scroll">

</div>
```

Then you need to apply the following styles:

```
.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Once the width inside the div exceeds either the screen width or the div width (you can define), it will apply the horizontal scroll bar.